# "Unable to find a version of runtime to run this application" for 32bit app on 64bit Windows

Tags: c#, .net, x86, 64-bit

I am developing a 32bit WinForm app (target: .NET 3.5). My client **insists** the app be installed into "Windows\System32\clientname" folder and autostarts on startup. Also, the app **must** be 32bit, so I can't use "Any CPU".

I am developing under Win7 x64 with VS2010 and all versions of .NET are installed. When I start the app I get the message "Unable to find a version of runtime to run this application".
On Win7 x86 it works without problem. It's not the app itself and I am 100% sure all the required frameworks are installed.

I know that on a x64 system this folder is not to be used for 32bit apps but as I said: client insists and won't budge.

Before I tell client definitively that it can't be done I want to explore all options. I googled of course and also searched this fine site but nothing helpful for my particular situation came up.

My app spawns another 32bit process located in the same folder. On x64 that didn't work either, of course, but I solved that by using "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection" and then copying it to another location to start it from there (which works fine).
I have done my homework but I just can't find a solution for starting the main app under x64 and in that particular folder.

Is there one?

Comment: Why can't you use Any CPU?  I bet that's the problem on your 64 bit system, and it won't harm running on a 32bit system at all.

Comment: Does the client have a reason for wanting it there?  Without wanting to sound patronising I assume that you've explained to him that C:\Windows is for Windows, not for applications.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about sounding patronising @AndrewCooper. I'll bet that not managing to ask it without sounding patronising was the OPs problem too! ;)

Comment: The app must be 32bit because it uses a 3rd part 32bit DLL. Of course I educated client with my limited diplomatic skills :). So, let's just assume all of those conditions are unchangeable. My question is: can it be done (using whatever tricks) or is it definitely not possible?

Comment: Here's an argument that may persuade your client, but your client sounds unreasonable.

All applications link to system DLLs. The first place that the loader looks for those DLLs is the directory in which the executable resides. That directory will have 64 bit DLLs which cannot be loaded into a 32 bit process.

Comment: Did you try putting the app in syswow64? Would client accept that?

Comment: You've been talking about your own machine, not the client's.  Is it a real problem?   The same trick could work on your own app, use a little bootstrapper EXE that just starts your main EXE that's stored in a proper folder.  Otherwise, no.

Comment: @David: yep, I told client that syswow64 would be the place to put it on x64 but it's a no-go. You know, I really enjoy a challenge and I'm happy to implement a work-around - even if complicated. There's always something new to learn in the process.

Comment: @Hans: Yes, I've thought about the bootstrapper (that's basically what I do with the other 32bit app that resides in the same folder). If the consensus here is that there's absolutely no work-around I will inform client and show him this discussion.

Comment: Why does the client want apps to live in system folder?

Comment: @David: Good question. Historic reasons, basically. The context of the app was developed before x64 and has always resided in that inappropriate folder. They don't want to change installer unless **absolutely** necessary... I'm fairly new on the team, so my word doesn't count that much yet.

Comment: Your client will find that the 32 bit installer will put the file in syswow64 unless file redirection is explicitly disabled.

Comment: I'm just trying to think outside the box here, but could you cheat a bit by having a symlink (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/ ) in that folder, so it seems like the app is there, but it really resides in a more 32-bit friendly folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an attempt to solve this problem I created two folders on my Win7 x64 machine:

- `C:\Windows\System32\ClientName`; and
- `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ClientName`

Next I created a simple x86 WinForms application targeting .NET 3.5. I found that if I copied the executable to `C:\Windows\System32\ClientName` I got exactly the same error message as you reported.

However, if I copied the executable to both directories, then I could start it from `C:\Windows\System32\ClientName`, and it worked just fine.

I did not try this, but I suspect that if you have a multi-assembly application, you only need to copy the `*.exe` file to `C:\Windows\System32\ClientName`. All of the other files (and the EXE) would then reside in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ClientName` directory.

This is a bit of an untidy solution, I know, but then again your client's requirement is a bit unusual to start with.

Comment: That looks like a solution. It's unusual but as you say so are the requirements. Thanks John!